# Determine whether a data element in a Pandas Dataframe is present in another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two Pandas Dataframes (df1 and df2), both of which have identical structures, and both of which have several hundred thousand rows.

I'd like to update a field for each row indicating whether the ID for the row is found anywhere in a field in the other dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['AAA',''],['BBB',''],['CCC','']], columns=['ID','Match'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['FFF',''],['BBB',''],['AAA',''],['BBB','']], columns=['ID','Match'])
```

And I'd like to end up with a result that looks like:

```
ID  Match
FFF N
BBB Y
AAA Y
BBB Y
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `join` the IDs in `df1` and use `str.contains` to identify the IDs that contains any ID from `df1`; then use `np.where` to assign "Y" if there is a match, "N" otherwise:

```
df2['Match'] = np.where(df2['ID'].str.contains('|'.join(df1['ID'])), 'Y', 'N')
```

Output:

```
    ID Match
0  FFF     N
1  BBB     Y
2  AAA     Y
3  BBB     Y
```

Comment: This looks like it works for the dataset I provided above.  When I ran it against the real dataset I'm using that has 300k records in the first dataframe and 900k records in the second, it ran for over 12 hours, and I had to cut it off.  I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do it; would you have any ideas?

Comment: @TimothyWhite My guess is that you ran into memory problems, rather than runtime problems. Anyway, you could try set operations: `df1_set = set(df1['ID']); ['Y' if df1_set.issuperset([x]) else 'N' for x in df2['ID']]`. In my benchmark, this is ~16x faster.